# Body background

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как лучше сделать `background`, когда есть фоновые изображения для `body` при верстке сайта с этого макета? Просто шаблон фиксированный. [image]

Comment: > Я в верстке новичокЭто поправимо: [Самоучитель CSS][1], [Самоучитель HTML][2]   [1]http://htmlbook.ru/samcss   [2]:http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не совсем ясен вопрос, если нужно сделать патерн для фона, то NeonDT прав,
если же нужно в один блок (body например) вставить несколько фонов то используй css3:

```
body {
   background-image:  url("img/img1.png"), url("img/img2.gif"), url("img/img3.jpg");  
   background-position: 20px 30px, bottom left, top left;
   background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
```

фоны перечисляются сверху вниз (первым указываешь верхнюю картинку, последним фоновую).
Кораткая запись:

```
  body {
       background: url("img/img1.png") 20px 30px no-repeat, 
                   url("img/img2.gif") bottom left repeat-x,
                   url("img/img3.jpg") top left repeat-y;          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно! Открываешь шаблон в "фотошопе" находишь в слоях участок с фоном, в твоем случае это серый, и вырезаешь из него маленькую полосочку, сохраняешь ее в формате .gif 
Дальше открываешь css стиль и "репитишь" это изображение по оси "х" и "у".

```
body {
            background: white url('/images/img.gif');
            background-repeat: repeat;
    }
```

Comment: В моём случае он не просто серый, а с рисунком. Давайте я вам дам свой скайп, и мы всё обсудим в переписке.